How to create a tabulated report based on data: using Proc Tabulate
How to create a tabulated report based on data:
Column CATEGORY in H means a horizontal report. TITLE_LEVELS indicate how many levels of title there are. TITLE_LEVEL1 is the main header, TITLE_LEVEL2 is the sub-header of TITLE_LEVEL1, and TITLE_LEVEL3 is the sub-header of TITLE_LEVEL2.
All columns are Character data type
i have data
enter image description here
proc tabulate data=datset;
class TITLE_LEVEL1 TITLE_LEVEL2 TITLE_LEVEL3 Column1  ;
table TITLE_LEVEL1*
TITLE_LEVEL2*TITLE_LEVEL3;
run;
i want
enter image description here

You will have to reshape your data structure into a categorical form appropriate for TABULATE
The data you want for TABULATE should have columns

SR_NO, label "Serial No"
STATE
Group
Gender
Count (Numeric value of that col1)

There would be 6 data rows, and the row1&2 from your image would be 'pivoted' into categorical variables 'SR_NO' and 'STATE' that would be a constant value over those 6 rows.
and the TABULATE
  CLASS SR_NO STATE Group Gender ;
  VAR Count ;
  TABLE SR_NO * STATE , GROUP * GENDER * COUNT*MIN

Do you have access to the raw data that was used to create the data shown in image 1?  If so, tabulate can likely operate on that without reshaping.
